# Posting Documentation onto a Joomla Site

Tags: documentation, joomla, components

I would like to create some documentation and post it onto my Joomla website.  This documentation would be something along the lines of the MSDN documentation: i.e. each page would follow a basic template.

Intuitively I feel I have two ways of achieving this:

1) Creating each page of documentation as a separate article, and then linking them up.

2) Creating some kind of template and filling the information from a database.

The second option being preferable in the long run.  Unforunately I have no idea how to achieve what I'm looking for.  I hoped that there would be a component out there that woud help me, but Googling for 'Joomla Documentation' just brings up the documentation for Joomla itself.

Has anyone out there put documentation on their site, and how did they achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably best off using one of the content construction kits (CCKs) available for Joomla: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/news-production/content-construction These allow you to define preset fields for each article.

Comment: Thanks - I'd been looking in entirely the wrong area.